# Is this a good place to ask about manga canon, such as One Piece?

Tags: discussion

The title pretty much covers it - I want to know if this is a good place to ask about One Piece.

I'm not sure if such questions would be better off on movies & tv SE

Comment: Why not ask on [anime.se]?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece), I immediately come across this line

> The world of One Piece is populated by humans and numerous other races, including mermen and mermaids, "fishmen" (a race of fish/human hybrid), and giants.

along with

> The group goes to Water 7, where they battle the cyborg shipwright Franky

These elements make the story on-topic here. However, you may find better experts or answers at the [Anime/Manga SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if One Piece would be considered on topic here, but it is most definitely on topic at [Anime and Manga SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/). They even have [a tag for it](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-piece), and we don't. So I'd ask over there.